# Debug CoffeeScript sources with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node-inspector

I'm using CoffeeScript for a while to write Node.js programs. It's ok to debug with `node-inspector` if I compile the sources with *Source Maps*.

However, when I try to create a mixed Javascript/CoffeeScript app by using `coffee-script/register`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('coffee-script/register');
require('../src/client');
```

Then, node-inspector shows the compiled Javascript.

Is there how to see the actual `*.coffee` sources in `node-inspector` when I'm not explicity compiling it?

Comment: I don't think so. If I want to see a small portion of my code compiled, my editor plugin allows me to just compile a selection. Here's what I use: https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script but I think its available for most editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Node Inspector*

In order to see the actual `*.coffee` file in Node Inspector, you need to provide a source-map file describing how to map the transpiled javascript loaded inside Node/V8 runtime to you coffee-script source. Additionally, the filename of the transpiled javascript must be different from the original script name (AFAIK).

This is the trouble with `require('coffee-script/register')`: it converts the coffee-script source to the javascript source while keeping the same file name. In other words, the runtime (and Node Inspector) see that your `*.coffee` contain the transpiled javascript, thus it cannot display your coffee script for that very same filename. Also AFAIK, the coffee compiler does not emit any source map in this case.

I see two possible approaches to fix the problem:

1. Modify `loadFile()` in `coffee-script/register`:

   - emit a source map and save it to a file
   - pass a different filename to `module._compile`, e.g. `script.coffee.js`
2. Modify `coffee-script/register` to emit an embedded source map. Fix Chrome DevTools and/or Node Inspector to support embedded source maps.

References:

- `loadFile()` in [coffee-script/register](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/a563e8f8fe0d99d6f107dedb26e8680915bc1d78/lib/coffee-script/register.js#L13-L17)
- A Node Inspector issue discussing why `coffee --nodejs --debug app.coffee` does not work now: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/224
- A Node Inspector issue discussing inline source maps: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/401